# Add HTML tags into json response and render like html

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, json, django

I am using Python Django as REST API, Angular-2 as front end. With every request, I am getting a response in form of JSON. I want to highlight a few words in my JSON response. So I want to add few HTML tags like `<b>` from the Python code itself and the browser should render it as HTML `<b>` tag only.

But the browser doesn't understand `<b>` coming with in JSON response and displays as plain text only.

Comment: How you are rendering into html. Post your code

Comment: post your code please and returned json

Comment: Below is my json: See result array. result array is passed to a angular list. I want few words in Text column  to be printed with <b> tag. If i insert <b> from python then browser doesnt understand that.[  
   
      'results':[  
         {  
            'lineNumber':1,
            'text':'Feb  3 06:13:36 snx11247n000 user_activity_log: user=root, CWD=/home/admin/FOFB, /dev/pts/26, EXIT=0, CMD=./lus-ho.sh_cscli_and_kill_14hours\n',
            'context':None
     },  
      ]

Comment: You can see text column in result array. Using angular 2 ngFor rendering my result list. Now list has a column named "text" i want few words in that string to be printed as bold. I want to decide this from python. is it possible if yes then how? or any other way??

Comment: Edit the question in order to add the requested info. Never use comments for posting code data!